# Does space have the same salvage laws as maritime law?

Tags: artificial-satellite, law

With the international space station being decommissioned within the decade and other abandoned satellites what are the rules on independently saving these objects?

Comment: Has anything actually been abandoned in a long-term stable orbit which is useful and economical to claim and refurbish instead of replace? The cost of salvage would be, ahem, astronomical.

Comment: I've submitted a vote to close as a duplicate for a related question about salvaging lunar equipment. To my knowledge the answer covers all the same ground that an answer to this would.

Comment: @StarfishPrime I'm no expert in anything maritimeish or lawish, but I think that salvage is about recovering some otherwise lost *value*, and is not limited to refurbishment and reuse. So if you pull an old first stage engine off of the ocean floor that didn't originally belong to you, clean it up and put it in your living room or sell it to a museum, your right to keep it for whatever reason you like might also fall under the umbrella term "salvage law". See for example [Could parts be salvaged off the Apollo thrusters found on the ocean floor?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/2685/12102)

Comment: @StarfishPrime also slightly related [What happens to rocket stages that land in the oceans, and how many are still there?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/30927/12102) and [Do space industry companies want their defunct satellites back?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/53720/12102)

Comment: @Joe if that's what you mean then I think you should click "edit" under your question and make that clearer. If you are specifically asking about refurbishment and reuse, or recovering cash compensation from the original owners, you should make that clear as well. It's hard to say if you want to *claim ownership* or *repair and return to service for financial reward*. Thanks!

Comment: See also [this answer to *Legality of nuclear debris field on the Moon?*](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/57245/12102) which links to the old TV show *Salvage 1* ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salvage_1), [IMDB](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0078681/)) and includes a [screenshot of Andy Griffith in a space suit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nzGI6.jpg) something you don't see every day!  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=saPerT1lpJA&t=191s

Comment: @StarfishPrime, I'm sure the NSA would *love* to get their hands on a derelict Russian surveillance satellite.

Comment: @Mark the NSA famously adheres to international law in all aspects of its work, so I'm sure they'd keep their hands off any russian satellite stuff if there was any hint of impropriety.

Comment: @StarfishPrime, you can't sneak up on things in space.  Claiming salvage rights on a derelict would generate much less of an international incident than stealing it outright.

Comment: @Mark yep, I'm sure once you've told the russians it isn't _stealing_, its just _salvaging_, they'll just sigh and nod leave you to it.